# intrinsic definition of "affine open"

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $X$ be a scheme. I was trying to think of an *intrinsic* (or *coordinate free*, if you like) way to characterize all affine open $U\subset X$.  For instance, something like "$U$ is open and points of $U$ correspond bijectively to prime ideals in $O_X(U)$ via $$p\mapsto \{f \in O_X(U): \text{the germ of $f$ at $p$ is contained in the maximal ideal of}~ O_{X,p}\}.$$

I don't know if that works, but is there some such characterization?

Comment: You're aware that affine schemes are exactly those schemes $X$ for which $\operatorname{Spec} \mathcal{O}_X(X) \cong X$, right?

Comment: @KReiser yes. i wondered if there is a way to define affine besides "isomorphic to spec of a ring." assuming X is already a scheme.

Comment: @Tim Kinsell: one could also use Serre's criterion of affineness to 'define' affine schemes, but this is brutal.

Comment: @Gaussian thanks I'll have a look at that.

Comment: basically my thinking was: in the examples i know of non-affine schemes -- take for instance $P^n_k$ and $A_k^n-\{(x_1,...,x_n)\}$ -- we know they are not affine either because of a dearth of global sections (as in the projective case) or a dearth of points (as in the punctured affine case), so maybe theres a way to say "affine" by just requiring that points and (prime ideals of) sections fit together in some way, thus   giving a completely intrinsic definition of affineness.